# Responsive Website Generator - Is It Possible?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So, there are a million tools out there on making responsive HTML5 websites.

Do you think it's possible, or know of anything out there, to have someone upload their old school website and have software spit out an HTML5 mobile/responsive website?

Comment: Responsive websites really depend on how the content is laid out. Its highly unlikely there is a tool that will accurately do this. The tool would need to know and understand where the site breaks and add breakpoints etc. Your best bet is to use a responsive framework like bootstrap and create a basic responsive content structure that the existing site can use  (i.e collapsing columns etc) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your self. all of them generate tools mean, no needed developers and Supports. some work have make manually. and no tool available in Web market.

Try this http://www.responsivehtmlfactory.com/. but it payable and they are do it also Manual work and have some much time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm a web designer, or at least I masquerade as one in comparison to the skills of contributors here, so I can design something for mobile that would appear like someone's full width site but was wondering if this could be automated. It would be a great tool!